# Expected unqualified-id before 'void' c++

Tags: c++

I am getting the error in the first two functions 'input' and 'genWindows'. I have never had this error and can't seem to figure out what could be causing it nor why the class is considered unqualified.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Queue.h"
#include "window.h"
#include "sim.h"

using namespace std;

string fileInput;
ifstream file;
string line;
window* windows;
Queue<int>* queue = new Queue<int>;
Queue<int>* timeQueue = new Queue<int>;
Queue<int>* numStudent = new Queue<int>;
int simTime;
int numWindows;
int count;
bool check;
int numWinIdle;
int winIdle;

sim::void input()
{
    cout << "Please enter a file name: " << endl;
    cin >> fileInput;
}

sim::void genWindows()
{
    file.open(fileInput.c_str());
    if(file.good())
    {
        getline(file, line);
        numWindows = atoi(line.c_str());
        windows = new window[numWindows];
    }
    file.close();
}


sim::void placeStudent(int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numWindows; ++i)
    {
        if(windows[i].isEmpty())
        {
            numWinIdle++;
            winIdle += windows[i].idleTime;
            windows[i].idleTime = 0;
            windows[i].sTime = n;
            break;
        }
    }
}

sim::void removeStudent()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numWindows; ++i)
    {
        if(windows[i].sTime <= simTime)
        {
            windows[i].sTime = 0;

        }
    }
}

sim::void setIdleTime()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numWindows;++i)
    {
        if(windows[i].isEmpty())
        {
            windows[i].idleTime += (simTime - windows[i].idleTime);
        }
    }
}

sim::void getIdleTime()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numWindows;++i)
    {
        if(windows[i].idleTime != 0)
        {
            numWinIdle++;
            winIdle += windows[i].idleTime;
        }
    }
}
sim::void genQueue()
{
    file.open(fileInput.c_str());
    int numStudents;
    check = true;
    getline(file,line);
    while(file >> line)
    {
        if(numStudents > 0)
        {
            queue->pushOn(atoi(line.c_str()));
            --numStudents;
        }
        else if(check)
        {
            timeQueue->pushOn(atoi(line.c_str()));
            check = false;
        }
        else
        {
            numStudent->pushOn(atoi(line.c_str()));
            numStudents = atoi(line.c_str());
            check = true;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}

sim::bool checkWindows()
{   
    for(int i = 0; i < numWindows; ++i)
    {
        if(windows[i].isEmpty())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}

sim::int numWinOpen()
{
    int count;
    for(int i = 0; i < numWindows; ++i)
    {
        if(windows[i].isEmpty())
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

sim::void simulationTime()
{
    if(timeQueue->isEmpty())
    {
        simTime++;
    }
    else
    {
        simTime = timeQueue->getFront();
        timeQueue->popOff();
    }
}

sim::void runSim()
{       
    if(checkWindows() && queue->isEmpty())
    {   
        cout<<winIdle<<endl;
        cout<<numWinIdle<<endl;
        double mean = winIdle/double(numWinIdle);
        cout<<"Registrar cleared"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {

        simulationTime();
        removeStudent();
        while(numWinOpen() > 0)
        {
            if(queue->isEmpty())
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(numStudent->isEmpty())
            {
                if(numWinOpen() > 0 && queue->isEmpty() == false)
                    placeStudent(queue->getFront() + simTime);
                    queue->popOff();
            }
            else if(numStudent->getFront() > numWinOpen())
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < numWinOpen();++i)
                {
                    if(numWinOpen() > 0 && queue->isEmpty() == false)
                        placeStudent(queue->getFront() + simTime);
                        queue->popOff();
                }
                numStudent->popOff();
            }
            else if(numStudent->getFront() <= numWinOpen())
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < numStudent->getFront();++i)
                {
                    if(numWinOpen() > 0 && queue->isEmpty() == false)
                        placeStudent(queue->getFront() + simTime);
                        queue->popOff();
                }
                numStudent->popOff();
            }
        }
        setIdleTime();
        runSim();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`sim::void` is nonsense. You mean `void`.

If the function was declared in a namespace, then it's the function name, not the return type, that needs qualifying:

```
void sim::input()
```

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense:

```
sim::void input()
```

I think you meant this:

```
void sim::input()
```